# How to type branches of normalized state tree?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a question about typing normalized state tree in `ngrx` library. For example:

```
const initialState: State = {
    dependencies: {
        1: {
            id: 1,
            name: "dependency1",
            type: "basic"
        },
        2: {
            id: 2,
            name: "dependency2",
            type: "complex"
        },
        3: {
            id: 3,
            name: "dependency3",
            type: "basic"
        }
    },
    dependencyIds: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Ok, so we can declare `dependencyIds` as `number[]` in `State` interface, and it's pretty clear. **But question is:** Is there a way to type `dependecies` as Object, within every parameters are a `Dependency` objects?

smth like:

```
export interface State {
    dependencies: any,  <--- is there a {Dependency} instead of 'any' type, or sth?
    dependencyIds: number[]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use  `dependencies: { [key: number]: {...}`

```
interface State {
    dependencies: { [key: number]: {
        id: number,
        name: string,
        type: "basic" | "complex"
    } }
    dependencyIds: number[]
}
```

Or with a subsequent interface:

```
interface State {
    dependencies: { [key: number]: Dependency},
    dependencyIds: number[];
}

interface Dependency {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    type: "basic" | "complex"
}
```